# Variables in Chatterbot conversations

Tags: python, chatbot, chatterbot

I would like to build a simple chatbot understanding some variables, names etc.
Example:
Bot: What is your name?
User: My name is John(user's name)
Bot: Nice to meet you John(as you can see it understands the name and uses it in conversation)

My question is: Does the chatterbot provides this feature? If so, what to use in chatterbot to create it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking forward to having a list of phrases that understands variables, you could do this:

```
if 'my name is ' in response.lower():
    index=response.lower().find('my name is ')+11 #index of start of name
    indexspace=response[index:].find(' ')+index #find index of space after name, indexspace gives result in terms of the index for response[index:], not response itself, so +index
    if indexspace==-1:
        name=response[index:].replace('.','') #handle 'My name is Joe.' without space at the end
    else:
        name=response[index:indexspace].replace('.','').replace(',','') #handle 'My name is Joe, nice to meet you!'
    print('Nice to meet you, '+name)
else:
    print('Hi, what is your name?')
```

You could add more clauses with replace for more punctuation, and random responses. You could also add more of these with different declaration phrases.

If you are looking forward to doing something more general, without special cases for variable declaration I suggest looking at Machine Learning for chatbots, which require chatting data and analysis to determine the declaration phrases, or more often, simply gives an response.